# D3.js not defined, express serving up static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, d3.js

I've got express serving up static js files, and a local copy of d3.js (v4) is among them. All the other js files load from my  tags, but it says d3 is not defined. I've tried loading from a url too, but no dice, jquery loads fine ("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js") but not d3 ("https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js").

Clearly it is able to locate the resource, because I don't get a 404, but it never runs. When I throw a console.log('hello') into the d3 source, it doesn't show up.

I've tried it in Chrome and Firefox.. I've seen answers that say to use http-server, but isn't express's static server doing the same thing?

Thanks in advance if you've got an idea.

file structure:

[image]

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const routes = require('./routes');
const graph = require('./graph');

//urls to use
const localMongoUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test";

const url = localMongoUrl

//connect to db. make sure mongo daemon is running.
mongoose.connect(url);
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.on('error', err => console.err(err));
connection.on('open', err => {
  if (err) console.err(err);
  else console.log('connected to ' + url);
});

//middleware attaches form info to req.body
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//set up pug as the templating engine
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

//serve up files in public folder
app.use(express.static('public'));

//setup router as middleware
app.use('/', router);

//serve up the index page when root is hit
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  connection.db.listCollections().toArray((err, collections) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.json(err);
      res.end();
    } else {
      const collectionNames = collections.map(collection => {
        return collection.name;
      })
      req.collectionNames = collectionNames;
      res.render('layout', { names: req.collectionNames, url: url });
    }
  });
})

//route for when user selects which collection in dropdown
router.use('/collections', routes);
router.use('/graph', graph);

//listen for requests
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on 3000');
});
```

graph.pug

```
html
  head
    title GateCounts Graph
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/barchart.css")
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/pikaday.css")
  body
    .page-wrapper
      .row
        .col-md-2
          h1 D3 Graph w/ Mongodb
          .form-wrapper#graph-query
            form(method="POST" action="/graph/getgraph")
              fieldset.form-group
                legend Date Range
                  input.form-control(type="text" id="fromDate" name="fromDate" placeholder="From:")
                  input.form-control(type="text" id="toDate" name="toDate" placeholder="To:")
              fieldset.form-group
                div.form-check
                  label.form-check-label(for="sunday") Sunday&nbsp&nbsp
                    input.form-check-input(type="checkbox" id="sunday" name="weekdays" value="1" checked)
                div.form-check
                  label.form-check-label(for="monday") Monday&nbsp&nbsp
                    input.form-check-input(type="checkbox" id="monday" name="weekdays" value="2" checked)
                div.form-check
                  label.form-check-label(for="tuesday") Tuesday&nbsp&nbsp
                    input.form-check-input(type="checkbox" id="tuesday" name="weekdays" value="3" checked)
                div.form-check
                  label.form-check-label(for="wednesday") Wednesday&nbsp&nbsp
                    input.form-check-input(type="checkbox" id="wednesday" name="weekdays" value="4" checked)
                div.form-check
                  label.form-check-label(for="thursday") Thursday&nbsp&nbsp
                    input.form-check-input(type="checkbox" id="thursday" name="weekdays" value="5" checked)
                div.form-check
                  label.form-check-label(for="friday") Friday&nbsp&nbsp
                    input.form-check-input(type="checkbox" id="friday" name="weekdays" value="6" checked)
                div.form-check
                  label.form-check-label(for="saturday") Saturday&nbsp&nbsp
                    input.form-check-input(type="checkbox" id="saturday" name="weekdays" value="7" checked)
              fieldset.form-group
                div.form-check
                  label.form-check-label(for="sunday") Include Closed Days?&nbsp&nbsp
                    input.form-check-input(type="checkbox" id="includeClosed" name="includeClosed" value="true" checked)
              button.btn(type="submit") Submit
              hr
          .summaryBox
            h4 Summary
            ul.list-group#summary-list
        .col-md-10
          h4 GateCounts Graph
          .graphBox
            #graph
script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js")
script(scr="js/d3.js")
script(src="js/barchart.js")
script(src="js/pikaday.js")
script(src="js/initGraph.js")
script(src="js/events.js")
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe try not using CDN?

Comment: I've tried a locally downloaded copy also, same result.

Comment: you got some code to show us?

Comment: express requires additional coding, and `http-server` does not requires anything, it just serves

Comment: sure, wasn't sure what to even share, i've included my .pug template and app.js

Comment: where is the part of the code are you trying to access the d3 global variable?

Comment: it is in a file called barchart.js, which literally just has 'console.log(d3)' in it at this point. d3 doesn't show up on window when I look in the browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're serving your static files out of your `./public` directory under the same directory that `app.js` is in. Under that folder you need to have a `js` directory with `d3.js` under that. If you installed [D3 from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3), then it will be in your `<project root>/node_modules` and you'll need to find the d3.js from there and copy it over. You can make build tasks do this with a ton of tools to automate it.

Make sure the file is in `public/js` and that it's correct. Then try again.

EDIT: To add to that, if you are checking your Network tab in dev tools and you aren't 404'ing this, go to the line that is asking for d3.js and click on it, then on the response tab. See what you **do** get, because that can say a lot about what is wrong.

EDIT #2: Could also be a typo in `script(scr="")` :)

Comment: Hi, added a pic of my file structure above, and one of my network tab... it doesn't look like there is any attempt to load it?

Comment: @zbnrg in `graph.js` are you using `res.render('graph')`? Then you've edited the pug page and refreshed it and you still get that in the network tab? Do you get errors in your Console tab? (Just ruling out the simple solutions)

Comment: right, that's what it looks like when I hit refresh, the only error I get is that d3 is not defined when called in barchart.js.

Comment: It might just be the pasting, but are those script tags indented correctly on your to be under the body tag in your pug?

Comment: yeah, ha, i had some trouble pasting it in, in my pug file they are lined up with the body tag

Comment: I'd ask for one last sanity check, if you don't mind. Can you make some other change on the pug, and verify that you can see the change? I'm wondering at this point if your browser has cached a previous version of the file that didn't have that script tag.

Comment: In chrome dev tools you can set it to never use cache when you have them open. I'm seeing 304's on your network tab picture, which means it's using the cached versions of the files instead of asking for them brand new again, so cache seems likely. If you want, I also don't mind moving this to the chat and trying to help. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144006/discussion-between-zbnrg-and-jeremy-pridemore).